# Access element values in a table using Jsoup in Java

Tags: java, datatable, jsoup

I want to access certain values in this large table on this website:

http://www.hmdb.ca/metabolites/HMDB01448

For example, I want to access "Common Name" --> "Sulfate"

My current solution is:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
     Elements tables = doc.select("table.content-table.table.table-condensed.table-bordered"); 
     for (Element table : tables) {
        for (Element header : table.select("th")) {
           Elements strong = header.select("strong");
              System.out.println(strong.get(0).text());
        }
     }
  }
```

For some reason, this is not working. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: My question is different from existing questions because I do not know what exact cell to search for, for different iterations of the program will yield different chemical names (not only Sulfate).

Answer (score 0):

You can access all rows in two steps:

- firstly you need to pick all rows with `td` (it will filter out header rows). This can be done with following expression: `table.content-table > tbody > tr:has(td)`
- next you need to iterate over all rows and pick `th` and `td`. You can extract text from `th` using `text()` method, but in case of `td` I would recommend extracting value with `html()` method since it may contain plain text as well as some HTML like lists etc.

Take a look at this example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

final class JsoupTableReadExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final URL url = URI.create("http://www.hmdb.ca/metabolites/HMDB01448").toURL();
        final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 4000);

        final Elements rows = doc.select("table.content-table > tbody > tr:has(td)");

        for (Element row : rows) {
            String name = row.select("th").first().text();
            String value = row.select("td").first().html();

            System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can play around with it and find best fitting solution to solve your problem. I hope it helps.